# Prove a function is bijective

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given any set *A*, the *identity function on A* is $I_A: A \rightarrow A$ defined by $I_A(x) = x$ for any  $x ∈ A$. Show that the identity function is a bijection.

**Attempt:**

Suppose $\,f: A \rightarrow A$, then $f$ is **bijective** if it is both *injective* and *surjective*.

*Injective:* Pick $x,y \in A$ such that $f(x) = f(x)$. So $I_A(x) = I_A(y)$, that is, $x = y$. Thus $I_A$ is injective by its definition.

*Subjective:* Next pick $y \in A$ such that $f(y) = x$. So $I_A(y) = x$. So, $A \subseteq I_A$, that is, A is in the range of $I_A$ and $y \in A$. Thus $I_A$ is subjectively by its definition that any element in the function must be in the range of the function.

$☐$

Comment: So, you have the problem statement, and you have the relevant definition. Have you tried showing that this function satisfies the definition? Is it injective? Is it surjective? Where are you stuck?

Comment: It looks better now, but to show that the function is surjective is even simpler (even trivial). If $x\in A$, then $I_A(x)=x$, done! :) In other words, just pick $y=x$.

Comment: Great improvement, given your edit!

Comment: I took a look at the help page and am having difficulty understanding why the question was placed on hold. Would anyone be able to help/explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

- The function is injective if $I_A(x)=I_A(y)\Rightarrow x=y$
- The function is surjective if you can find some $y$ such that $I_A (y)=x$